# Unable to connect to dynamoDB table - UnknownEndpoint: Inaccessible host:

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I'm new to dynamoDB. I have created a table and am trying to insert data into the table. It works well when I connect from my home internet. But when I try from my office network, I get the below error:

I suspect this is due to proxy issues. Can you please help me resolve this issue? Thank you.

[UnknownEndpoint: Inaccessible host: `dynamodb.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com'. This service may not be available in the`ap-southeast-2' region.]
  message: 'Inaccessible host: `dynamodb.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com\'. This service may not be available in the`ap-southeast-2\' region.',
  code: 'UnknownEndpoint',
  region: 'ap-southeast-2',
  hostname: 'dynamodb.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com',
  retryable: true,
  originalError: 
   { [NetworkingError: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND dynamodb.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com dynamodb.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com:443]
     message: 'getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND dynamodb.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com dynamodb.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com:443',
     code: 'NetworkingError',
     errno: 'ENOTFOUND',
     syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
     hostname: 'dynamodb.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com',
     host: 'dynamodb.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com',
     port: 443,
     region: 'ap-southeast-2',
     retryable: true,
     time: Mon Sep 21 2015 11:19:58 GMT+1000 (AUS Eastern Standard Time) },
  time: Mon Sep 21 2015 11:19:58 GMT+1000 (AUS Eastern Standard Time) }

Comment: You probably need to configure the proxy settings on the [`ClientConfiguration`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/ClientConfiguration.html).

Comment: @mkobit could you please explain me a bit. I'm experiencing the same here.Not able to figure out the solution yet.

Comment: @JayendranRosh your corporate (or whatever you are using) network may not allow you to access those AWS resources so you may need to go through a proxy. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/section-client-configuration.html is for the Java SDK, but something similar exists in all of the SDKs.

Comment: @mkobit Thanks, for the clarification. After this issue, I've also experienced like *The security token included in the request is invalid* When I create a new access token id and secret id it works fine. I think it's wired to create a new access token id and secret for every command! Is there is an expiration for the access token's credentials?

Comment: @JayendranRosh It's difficult to say without an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - there are different ways of provisioning credentials, and some of them are temporary (for example, [this documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_credentials_temp_request.html).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the pointers. I managed to solve the issue using below code snipped.

```
var proxy = require('proxy-agent');
AWS.config.update({
    httpOptions: {
        agent: proxy('http://{user_name}:{password}@<proxy>:<port>')
    }
});
```

This is documented in amazon's aws-sdk configuration site: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/guide/node-configuring.html